# Importing data with multiple IDs

Tags: python

I need to import some data onto a server. The problem I have is the data isn't quite in the right format. To put it simply, it looks like this:

```
ITEMS_DIREC

ID | Co-ordinate
1  | 648
2  | 25
2  | 305
2  | 307
2  | 569
3  | 354
3  | 450
3  | 573
4  | 293
4  | 449
5  | 25
5  | 73
```

I want it to look something more like this:

```
1  | 648
2  | 25, 305, 307, 569, 
3  | 354, 450, 573,
4  | 293, 449
5  | 25, 73
```

This is the code I have to alter (this code assumes that each ID is unique, so no multiples like above):

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, iid, name):
        self.iid = iid
        self.name = name

class Data:
    def __str__(self):
        return "Item[iid=%s,name=%s]" % (self.iid, self.name)

    def __init__(self):
        self._items = {} 
        self._items_file = "%s/%s" % (DATA_DIREC, ITEMS_DIREC)

    def add_item(self, item):
        self._items[item.iid] = item

    def __init_items(self):
        f = open(self._items_file, 'r')
        for line in f:
            data = line.rstrip('\r\n').split("|")
            self.add_item(Item(data[0], data[1]))
        f.close()
        print "Items added" % len(self._items)
```

So I get the impression that if I use this code on my original data, it won't consider the multiple ID's as one in the same. Not only that, but my data set is quite large (100,000+) and not every ID has the same number of co-ordinates so I can't simply construct a matrix and fill in the values.

Can anyone give me some help in the right direction? I'm not at all experienced with Python so everything I've tried so far has failed quite miserably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` to handle pipe delimited data and a `collections.defaultdict` to accumulate each value for key id. You can use `islice` to conveniently skip the first few rows that you don't require, then for final output, sort the rows by id and then write them out followed by a comma delimited list of values. eg:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
with open('input') as fin:
    pipe_in = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='|')
    for key, val in islice(pipe_in, 3, None):
        dd[key].append(val)

with open('output', 'wb') as fout:
    pipe_out = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|')
    pipe_out.writerows([k, ', '.join(v)] for k, v in sorted(dd.iteritems()))

# 1|648
# 2|25, 305, 307, 569
# 3|354, 450, 573
# 4|293, 449
# 5|25, 73
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I will try and attempt what you've suggested and report back.